# Database schema for end of day process

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I got a POS and inventory system which contains a receipt table for the invoice headers and a receipt_lines Table for the contents in it. where the user have to press a close of day button at the end of day for the table to be dropped and recreated and the invoice number would start again from 1 at the next day. The data in the past table would be copied to a historic table before the current table is dropped.

I wonder if there is a better way to do design this schema where the receipt number resets every day and stays the primary key:

- Receipt table
  **receiptid      receiptdate    amount    clientnumber**
- receipt_lines
  **itemcode       receiptID     quantity     unit_price**

Comment: Looking at the tables, are both of these tables copied to history tables before being dropped? If so, how do you know what `receiptID` in the `receipt_lines` history table goes with the `receiptID` in the `Receipt` history table if the `receiptID` is reset?

Comment: Seems to me you are putting too much importance on the receiptID. A primary key may NOT have duplicates ever. There is no work around for this. And why does it matter if the value resets every day? That seems like maybe not a good idea.

Comment: sean, employee shifts occur and my clients need to keep track on the invoice number and current sales in each shift.

Comment: WEI_DBA yes ofcourse both tables would be copied to a one historic table. however, then each record would contain additional field in the new table which refers to the client number, receipt date, and time. i assigned in this table my date, time and receipt number as the primary key. I bilieve that this is not the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally clear what you doing but first you don't have to drop a table.
You can just truncate and reset identity:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Receipt ] GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Receipt ', RESEED, 0)
```

Second, it seems that you need to have a PK receiptdate & receiptID have a another table to just hold the receitID and reset that table every day. This way no need to copy any records just query based on receiptdate & receiptID, that way no needless and recource consuming of copying of historical receipts.

Thinking a little more about it you can just have a ReceitID table to hold a counter for each date (one row per date) that contains Date and ReceitId where Date is PK and ReceitID is just an integer, and increment this ReceitID on every insert. First increment that table then use that id in your  "Receipt" table.

Comment: i will check the truncate solution of yours. however, concerning the second solution, my client could do a closing within shifts(2-3 times a day). thus, the date and the id could not be assigned together as the primary key.

Comment: anyway what does the truncate do? xD

Comment: Truncate removes the records (truncate the table), it is mush faster than delete records in your situation it is appropriate.